# php file_get_contents HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 on asp

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm trying get a content HTML from a page in asp with `file_get_contents`.
When load  page with browser, it works, no problem.

To print status response I get 200 ok.

```
<%
Response.Write(Response.Status);
%>
```

But when I use `file_get_contents`, I get the error

```
 HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

if the cause from problem in firewall, is posible solved??
other can be cause from error?

Comment: What is `php_get_contents` ? o_O

Comment: did you mean file_get_contents?

Comment: Which script language are you actually executing? ASP or PHP? And where is the error? Unfortunately you are explicit with the working ASP code, but do not show the nonworking PHP code.

Comment: tha page is in ASP, but i try  get its content HTML with PHP, i get error with function file_get_contents.   thanks

Comment: 401 is a permissions problem with the target URL. Aside from that nugget we can't provide any other help since you have not posted any useful code to inspect.

Comment: mm, not, that's all, only, i load page in asp, when i try get content with php, appear the error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not fetching / passing the cookies generated by the ASP page.

Are you able to access the page directly using your browser (after deleting the browser cookies)?

Other possibility, is that the ASP page is validating the User-Agent or Referer strings.

It's hard to know exactly without more information...